# How to create new variable conditional on missingness on others in dplyr, R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider these data:

```r
library(dplyr)

d <- tibble(student.status = c(0, 1, NA, 0, 1, 1),
            student.school.hs = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA),
            student.school.alths = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1),
            student.school.allNA = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)) 

  student.status student.school.hs student.school.alt… student.school.…
           <dbl>             <dbl>               <dbl> <lgl>           
1              0                NA                  NA TRUE            
2              1                 1                  NA FALSE           
3             NA                NA                  NA TRUE            
4              0                NA                  NA TRUE            
5              1                NA                  NA TRUE            
6              1                NA                   1 FALSE
```

- I want to assign "0" to `student.school.*` when `student.status == 1` and when all of the `student.school.*` columns are not NA.
- If all of the `student.school.*` colums are NA and `student.status == 1`, then leave them NA.
- If `student.status == 0` then all the `student.school.*` columns should stay NA

The final data should look like:

```r
  student.status student.school.hs student.school.alt… student.school.…
           <dbl>             <dbl>               <dbl> <lgl>           
1              0                NA                  NA TRUE            
2              1                 1                   0 FALSE           
3             NA                NA                  NA TRUE            
4              0                NA                  NA TRUE            
5              1                NA                  NA TRUE            
6              1                 0                   1 FALSE
```

Comment: @akrun I have fixed the example, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps - loop `across` columns that `starts_with` the prefix 'student.school' in column name, while remove the logical column from the selection (`-where(is.logical)` - as `student.school.allNA` also have the same prefix but different column type), then use `case_when` to change the value of the columns when it is an `NA`, and if the `student.school.allNA` are FALSE (negated (`!`), along with `student.status` is 1)

```
library(dplyr)
d <- d %>%
   mutate(across(c(starts_with('student.school'), - where(is.logical)),
   ~ case_when(student.status %in% 1 & !student.school.allNA & is.na(.x) ~ 0, 
     TRUE ~ .x)))
```

-output

```
> d
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  student.status student.school.hs student.school.alths student.school.allNA
           <dbl>             <dbl>                <dbl> <lgl>               
1              0                NA                   NA TRUE                
2              1                 1                    0 FALSE               
3             NA                NA                   NA TRUE                
4              0                NA                   NA TRUE                
5              1                NA                   NA TRUE                
6              1                 0                    1 FALSE
```